# How to find the difference equation directly from Direct Form II signal flow graph

Tags: linear-systems, z-transform

I am trying to solve for the difference equation of the following signal flow graph:

[image: Direct Form II]

I am aware that Direct Form II can be converted to Direct Form I, which finding the difference equation directly is much easier.
What I have come up with is defining an intermediate signal $v[n]$ as the top middle node. I get the following result,

$$\begin{align}
v[n] &= x[n] + \tfrac{3}{5}v[n-1] - \tfrac{38}{75}v[n-2] - \tfrac{2}{15}v[n-3] \\
y[n] & =v[n]-\tfrac{3}{10}v[n-1]+\tfrac{1}{3}v[n-2] \\
\end{align}$$

As you can see, $v[n]$ is recursively dependent on itself. I know I could transform the two difference equations into their system functions and multiply together, find the total system function, and then transform back to their total difference equation. But for practice, I would like to know if their is another way to do this. I would like to somehow find the total difference equation without using their system functions.

Any advice would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: well, the nice thing about Laplace Transform is that it turns a differential equation into an algebraic equation that one can solve.  likewise, the Z Transform turns a difference equation (even with recursion) into an algebraic equation that can be solved.  dunno off hand how to answer your direct question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Darkling, these things are quite clearly explained in standard signals & systems textbooks. But I assume you have little time left to read (as most undergraduate courseware are full of homeworks, preliminaries, and projects that most of which I believe become harmful as they consume a student's learning time; and just completing a homework or project without full understanding makes what sense..? anyway)

Consider the LCCDE associated with a causal LTI system (such a system is said to be at *initial rest* which assures that all the initial conditions are zero; i.e., no output occurs before an input is applied) :

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{N} a_k ~y[n-k] = \sum_{k=0}^{M} b_k ~ x[n-k] $$ The order is $\max\{M,N\}$.

Now the LCCDE can be considered to be a cascade of two LTI systems; the LHS represents an IIR-LTI system represented by $A(z)$ and RHS represents an FIR-LTI system represented by  $B(z)$. So the system can be represented with the following block diagrams:

$$ x[n] \rightarrow \boxed{ B(z) } \rightarrow v[n] \rightarrow \boxed{ \frac{1}{A(z)} }\rightarrow y[n] \tag{1}$$

or equivalently
$$ x[n] \rightarrow \boxed{ \frac{1}{A(z)} } \rightarrow v[n] \rightarrow \boxed{ B(z) } \rightarrow y[n]  \tag{2}$$

This follows from the fact that both cascaded systems are LTI and order of LTI systems can be interchanged which follows from the fact that **convolution** operator is **commutative** and **associative**; i.e., $$h_1[n] \star h_2[n] \star x[n] = h_2[n] \star h_1[n] \star x[n] $$

Now, the block diagram of (1) can be implemented with the following signal flow graph which yields a Direct-Form-I structure :

[image]

And, the block diagram of (2) can be implemented with the following signal flow graph which yields a Direct-Form-II structure:

[image]

The intermediate memory (delays) are merged and the signal flow graph is simplified into the canonical direct-form II form finally as (assuming $N > M$)

[image]

From this last figure, it can be deduced that your LCCDE relating the input $x[n]$to the output $y[n]$ is :

$$ y[n] - \frac{3}{5} y[n-1] + \frac{38}{75} y[n-2] + \frac{2}{15} y[n-3] = x[n] - \frac{3}{10} x[n-1] + \frac{1}{3} x[n-2] $$

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a simple way & I am generalising it, let us assume left side coefficients as $a_k$ & right side as $b_k$. Then system function H(z) is given by

$$H(z)=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^M b_k.z^{-k}} {1-\sum_{k=1}^N a_k.z^{-k}}$$

Therefore the total difference equation becomes

$$y(n)=\sum_{k=0}^M b_k.x(n-k)+ \sum_{k=1}^N a_k.y(n-k)$$

Answer (score 0):

You’ve already described how to find the form I difference equation. If you go through that process, you will find that your feed back coeffiencents in the first equation are applied to y and the feed forward coefficients in the second equation are applied to x.